# Join tables using a value inside a JSONB column postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, join, select

I have two tables in postgresql.

1. the first (product) has sku json row ([149461190])
2. the second (item) has an ordinary sku column

How can I join them on sku?
I tried this, but it didn't work.
cannot recognize input near 'jsonb_to_recordset' '(' 'ps' in joinSourcePart

```
  select * from product ps
, jsonb_to_recordset(ps.sku -> 'ps_sku') as (sku text)
join item v using sku
```

Comment: Please append your JSON structure and fields, Also which column on `item` table do you want to join?

Comment: json column from the first table looks like this 
column name sku [149408204], [149461190], [149422714]

Comment: the second table also has sku column, it contains sky's but not in a json: 149461190, 149422714

Comment: I want to join product.sku which is a json, on item.sku

Comment: You should change the data model and not use JSON or arrays for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this query help you, You can see data structure and sample data in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=566a74d67c48efc1b3ddc8d1823e0053)

```sql
select 
  *
from  
  product p
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(p.sku -> 'ps_sku') as j(sku)
  inner join item i on i.sku = j.sku :: numeric
```

Comment: Thanks, but again a mistake ->> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException:line 5:39 cannot recognize input near 'jsonb_array_elements_text' '(' 'p' in joinSourcePart